# Как можно пользоваться content_type в aiogram3.x . Конкретно проблема с обработкой сообщения в виде контакта

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

from aiogram.enums import content_type

@dp.message(content_type(types.ContentType.CONTACT))
async def get_contact(msg: Message):
contact = msg.contact
await msg.answer(f"Спасибо за контакт")

Answer (score 2):

Я смог найти ответ на свой же вопрос! Оказывается нужно было использовать в фильтрах F.contact и всё!

```
@dp.message(F.contact)
async def func_contact(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer(f'Контакт:{msg.contact.phone_number}')
```